# I want to use Huami Web API. How do I create a ZAB file?

Tags: android, flutter, xiaomi

I want to load data from Mi Band 7 using Huami Web API.
When I checked the API documentation, it said to register as a developer on the Huami site and register the app.
When I tried to register the app, it said a zab file was needed, which is a problem.

I'm currently working on an android app with flutter.
I can't find in the official documentation how to create a zab file.

Does anyone know how?